# Nginx reverse proxy to different server internally

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a nginx reverse proxy server (not working yet) set up on IP `XX.XX.XX.125` with traffic on my router from port 80 forwarding onto IP `XX.XX.XX.125` Now when I go to `applicationname.mydomain.com` I get that my IP can't be found but my IP is working fine from the DNS side of things. Makes me think that the issue is Nginx.

I have my location block set up as:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XX.108:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Which points to my application running. I can access it by going directly to it's IP:port number but can't access by the URL.

Is this a Nginx issue or have I likely messed something else up?

Comment: The exact error message would be helpful, but it doesn't sound like an error that could be generated by nginx.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille it literally is just saying the IP can't be found. Which makes 0 sense since the ip is correct so DNS is right (well can't see where it is wrong anyways with copy and paste then cmd testing). That only leaves my application and Nginx. Application is running fine when I do the internal IP in chrome. So literally leaves Nginx at fault unless it is something I am not thinking of.

Comment: Do you have an internal DNS?  What gives `nslookup applicationname.mydomain.com`?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille No internal DNS, looks like the DNS propagated now and I am getting a server took too long to respond. Before though when it was giving me the IP error I could ping it from outside my network and it worked just fine for a ping.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I fixed it and am not sure how. I got mad at it and spammed the nginx restart command and that solved it. I had been restarting after everything I changed so no clue why it worked when I spammed it.

Comment: I guess your browser cache had been fooling you.